# Beginning and commiting transaction in a bean with TransactionManagementType.BEAN when called from a bean with TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER

Tags: java, transactions, ejb, java-ee-8

In the second method I'm unable to start a new transaction because a transaction has already started in the first bean because it's managed by container.
Is there a way to manually manage transaction only in SecondBean without changing FirstBean to TransactionManagementType.BEAN.
How should I approach this problem?

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER) // default
public class FirstBean {

    @Inject
    private SecondBean secondBean;

    public void firstMethod() {
        secondBean.secondMethod();
    }
}

@Singleton
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class SecondBean {

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction tx;

    public void secondMethod() {
        try {
            tx.begin();
            // save some entity in database
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is OK. There is nothing to correct.

When running, the first Transaction must be suspended and the second transaction begins for its own, when finised the first transaction continues and is done at the end of the first method.

The Error Message is a BUG in the Container. (maybe you can send the complete error message)

Which Application Server are you using as Runtime?

I have tested your code with Payara and just added System.out.println(..)
ALL working fine.

Make sure you have the right import statement:

```
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
```

Comment: Would you please accept the answer? Just click on the grayed check mark besides the answer.